# Prevent Safari Extension popup from closing on input file selection

Tags: javascript, html, macos, safari, safari-extension

I am developing a Safari Web Extension that is a popup. In the popup I added a basic form with an input type file element in there. When I click on the input, the browser window to select a file opens, I choose a file and click "Upload", then the popup closes and loses all data when I reopen it. It there a way to prevent the popup from closing after I select the file?

The popup I refer is the one you define in the manifest.json of the extension. Like the image bellow:

[image]

**Edit:**

I could not find a good solution for this, so I decided to move my extension from the popup to a sidebar that I inject in the page when needed. That will be a solution until Safari fixes this behavior.

Comment: @starball Create a Safari Web Extension using Xcode, with the generate base code (it creates a project with a popup by default), you go to popup.html file and add <input type="file" /> and that is it. Once you test it, if select a file, the popup closes and you lose all data. It is hard to create a reproducible example of a Safari extension.

Answer (score 0):

You could use localStorage to save the file into a new variable using fileReader and saving it into localStorage. I don't necessarily have a good way to answer this question if there is no code nor example code to look at but maybe **converting the file into a base64 link that is saved in localStorage with the name as well? You can also save the file as a blob and send that blob to IndexedDB and retriving that file from IndexedDB whenever the window is opened.** **I recommend the localStorage method since its easier and more accessible to changes and cleaner. Also the 1st example is localStorage and 2nd is IndexedDB I hope this helps :)**

**P.S. - The code won't run on StackOverflow so try using a Live Server / Safari Extension / Locally**

```html
<html>
<body>
    <h1 style="left: 50%; position: absolute; transform: translateX(-50%);">Extension</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div style="left: 50%; position: absolute; transform: translateX(-30%);">
        <input type="file" name="fileInput" id="fileInput" style="z-index:-1; color:transparent; margin-right: -30%; position: relative;">
        <button type="submit" onclick="upload()">Submit</button>
        <label id="label" for="fileInput">Select file</label>
    </div>
    <script defer>
    //Check if file already exists
    let link = localStorage.getItem("fileLink");
    let name = localStorage.getItem("fileName");
    let fileInputElm = document.getElementById("fileInput");
    //Change label to file name
    if(link!==""){document.getElementById("label").innerText = name; file = link;}else{fileInputElm.color = "black";}
    //Convert to base64 link
    function upload(){
        //Set localStorage items
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(fileInputElm.files[0]);
        reader.onload=function(){
            link = reader.result;
            localStorage.setItem("fileLink", reader.result);
        };
        //Change label to file name onupload
        name = fileInputElm.value.substring(fileInputElm.value.lastIndexOf("\\")+1);
        localStorage.setItem("fileName", name);
        document.getElementById("label").innerText = name;

        //Now do whatever you want to do with the link and name
        //variable link - file's link (base64)
        //variable name - file's name
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <h1>Extension</h1>
  <form id="fileForm">
    <input type="file" id="fileInput">
    <button type="submit" id="submitButton">Upload</button>
  </form>

  <script defer>
    // Open IndexedDB database
    let openDB = indexedDB.open('FileDatabase', 1);
    openDB.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
        let db = event.target.result;
        let objectStore = db.createObjectStore('files', { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });
    };
    openDB.onsuccess = function(event) {
        let db = event.target.result;
        // Form submission event handler
        let fileForm = document.getElementById('fileForm');
        let submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
        
        fileForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // Get the selected file
            let fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
            let file = fileInput.files[0];

            // Check if file exists in IndexedDB
            let transaction = db.transaction(['files'], 'readonly');
            let objectStore = transaction.objectStore('files');
            let request = objectStore.getAll();

            request.onsuccess = function(event) {
              let files = event.target.result;
              if (files.length > 0) {
                // File already exists in IndexedDB, do something with it
                console.log('File already exists:', files[0]);
              } else {
                // File doesn't exist, save it to IndexedDB
                let transaction = db.transaction(['files'], 'readwrite');
                let objectStore = transaction.objectStore('files');
                let addRequest = objectStore.add(file);

                addRequest.onsuccess = function() {
                  console.log('File saved to IndexedDB');
                };
                addRequest.onerror = function(event) {
                  console.error('Error saving file:', event.target.error);
                };
              }
            };

            request.onerror = function(event) {
              console.error('Error checking for file:', event.target.error);
            };
        });
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```